# PHP JSON Highcharts render pie each array

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts

I have this code, but actually only draws one pie with all data. I want to draw one pie for each key `($row['servicio'])`. I don't know if it is possible to auto-generate a new DIV with `id="pie-KEY"` then tell the chart to render every new KEY to it's own DIV.

**PHP**

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlTotals)) {
    $json[$row['servicio']] = array(
        "OK" => intval($row["OK"]),
        "KO" => intval($row["KO"])
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {        
    var series = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: []
    }; 
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        series.data.push(["OK", value.OK]);
        series.data.push(["KO", value.KO]);
    });
    options.series.push(series);
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is workking...

```
$.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {        
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var series = {
            type: 'pie',
            data: []
        }; 
        var renderId = "pie-" + key;
        $('#charts').append('<div id="'+ renderId +'" class="pieChart"></div>');
        series.data.push(["OK", value.OK]);
        series.data.push(["KO", value.KO]);
        options.series.push(series);
        options.chart.renderTo = renderId;
        options.title.text = key;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        series.data = null;
    }); 
});
```